# Trouble with pslib installing gnudatalanguage

Tags: macports

Today i spent some hours trying to install the gnuplotlanguage package with macports, with this result every time i tried

```
--->  Computing dependencies for gnudatalanguage
--->  Dependencies to be installed: pslib
--->  Fetching archive for pslib
--->  Attempting to fetch pslib-0.4.5_6.darwin_15.x86_64.tbz2 from http://fco.it.packages.macports.org/mirrors/macports-packages/pslib/pslib
--->  Attempting to fetch pslib-0.4.5_6.darwin_15.x86_64.tbz2 from http://nue.de.packages.macports.org/pslib
--->  Attempting to fetch pslib-0.4.5_6.darwin_15.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/pslib
--->  Fetching distfiles for pslib
--->  Attempting to fetch pslib-0.4.5.tar.gz from http://fco.it.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports-distfiles/pslib
--->  Verifying checksums for pslib
--->  Extracting pslib
--->  Applying patches to pslib
--->  Configuring pslib
--->  Building pslib
--->  Staging pslib into destroot
Error: org.macports.destroot for port pslib returned: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install pslib
Please see the log file for port pslib for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_print_pslib/pslib/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: pslib
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port gnudatalanguage failed
```

I tried to follow solutions found googling some of the lines that i thought could be causing this problem.
From the [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2pedtcO2MfOOHloOERJajlvMTQ/view?usp=sharing), lines like:

1. `Can't run fetch on this port without elevated privileges. Escalating privileges back to root.`
2. `Can't run destroot under sudo without elevated privileges (due to mtree)`
3. `org.macports.destroot for port pslib returned: command execution failed`
4. `Error code: CHILDSTATUS 54561 2`

I unfortunately found that none of the proposed solutions worked.

Has anyone found the same issue, and solved it? I really need GDL for a project.

Comment: The real reason shows up further down in your log file, in line 817: `../libtool: line 1717: 54617 Abort trap: 6           strip -S /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_print_pslib/pslib/work/destroot/opt/local/lib/libps.a`. Please provide the Crash Log for strip from Console.app for further debugging.

Comment: Hi @neverpanic, thanks for your help. Here is the crash report https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2pedtcO2MfOYTdFNGpIUk5sSVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like a buffer overflow in `/opt/local/bin/strip`. You might want to deactivate the port that provides this file (check which one it is using `port provides /opt/local/bin/strip`, then deactivate it with `sudo port deactivate $portname`). Or, you could try cleaning pslib and running with `port -t` to enable trace mode, which will hide `/opt/local/bin/strip` and fall back to your host's `/usr/bin/strip`, which might not have the problem. Note that trace mode only works on 10.11 with released versions of MacPorts if SIP is disabled, which you have.

Comment: I'll try to do as you say (both methods) as soon as possible and give you feedback. Thanks again

Comment: The port that provides strip is cctools, and it has dependences which in turn have dependencies which in turn etc so it is too long, unless there is some command that allows me to deactivate recursively the ports (hoping i will remember which ones i have to reactivate). Also running sudo with -t did nothing. Here is [the log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2pedtcO2MfOMlFQdzNYQjVmT28)...